# How to iterate through an array of promises in node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous, promise

In javascript, I have an non flat array of Promises:

```
const array = [
  [ promise11, promise12.. promise1n ],
  [ promise21, promise22.. promise2n ],
  [ promise31, promise32.. promise3n ],
  ...  
  [ promisek1, promisek2.. promisekn ]
];
```

How do iterate through the array in such a fashion, where the next array of promises would start resolving ONLY after the previous array of promises have resolved? For instance I would like the script to wait until `[ promise11, promise12.. promise1n ]` promises resolve in parrallel, before  calling on to the next array of promises.

I am looking for a general solution as my application cannot know in advance how many calls it'll have to make (it's a webscraper).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* use a variation on the `Array#reduce` pattern:

```
array.reduce(
    (p, subArray) => p.then(() => Promise.all(subArray)),
    Promise.resolve()
);
```

That sets up a promise chain where each entry in the chain is the result of the promise from `Promise.all` for the subarrays in the array.

...but:

> ...where the next array of promises would start resolving ONLY after the previous array of promises have resolved?

That's not how promises work. Once you have the promise, the action it promises a result for is **already** in progress. You don't "start" it.

So **instead**, you'd want to make `array` an array of functions that start the processes in question and *return* promises, which is slightly different:

```js
function get(label) {
  console.log(label + "- starting");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(label + "- resolving");
      resolve(label);
    }, Math.random() * 500);
  });
}
const array = [
  [ get.bind(null, "1a"), get.bind(null, "1b"), get.bind(null, "1c") ],
  [ get.bind(null, "2a"), get.bind(null, "2b") ],
  [ get.bind(null, "3a"), get.bind(null, "3b"), get.bind(null, "3c"), get.bind(null, "3d") ]
];

array.reduce(
  (p, subArray) => p.then(() => Promise.all(subArray.map(f => f()))),
  Promise.resolve()
).then(() => {
  console.log("All done");
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Notice how the array is now an array of functions, which when called "start" the process and then return a promise. Our `Array#reduce` loop is only slightly modified: We use `Array#map` to call the functions for this subarray and get an array of their promises, which is what we feed into `Promise.all`. So all of the functions for a given subarray are called to start the work for that subarray, and then we wait unti they're all complete before continuing to the next subarray and having it start its work.

Comment: The second solution you posted worked brilliantly, but I still have to understand how. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: @simonas88: If there's anything I can explain further, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: `(p, subArray) => p.then(() => Promise.all(subArray.map(f => f())))`
This reducer seems to be the key in the solution. Am I correct to assume, that p.then() returns (therefore completing a single subArray) when Promise.all() resolves all promises in it's parameter?

Comment: @simonas88: `then` returns immediately. *What* it returns is the promise returned by `Promise.all`, which is settled later when all of the promises created in the `map` operation are settled. The `reduce` builds a chain of those "all" promises, each waiting for the one before it to resolve before calling its `then` callback and starting the next batch.

Comment: Ok, so, the reducer finishes really quickly, and returns a chain of unfulfilled promises? And since on the outside each link in the 'chain' contains a Promise.all() I get the sequential/parallel behavior that I was after?